# idempotent function optimization

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

Is there any way in C++ to enable CSE (common subexpression elimination) for idempotent function calls?

Gcc seems to be the only compiler even bothering with attributes for pure functions but interestingly there's no idempotent one for functions that do modify global state but will always do the same thing for the same input. So they could be CSE'd but not DCE'd and wouldn't have to return anything.